# Filtering Paginated Results Django

Tags: django, pagination, django-views

I extended ListView in Django to paginatedListView as following

```
class paginatedListView(ListView):
per_page = 20

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(paginatedListView,self).get_queryset().order_by('-creation_datetime')
    paginator = Paginator(qs,self.per_page)
    try:
        page_num = int(self.request.GET.get('p', '0'))
    except ValueError:
        page_num = 0

    try:
        page = paginator.page(page_num + 1)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    self.cl = InlineChangeList(self.request, page_num, paginator)
    self.paginator = paginator

    if self.cl.show_all:
        return qs
    else:
        return page.object_list

def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(paginatedListView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['cl'] = self.cl
    return context
```

Now I have another view which extends paginatedListView, the queryset of this view should contain Order instances that follow a condition so i try to apply filter in its get_queryset()

```
class orderList(paginatedListView):
template_name = "dashboard/reports.html"
model = Order
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(orderList,self).get_queryset().filter(Order_status=Order.ORDER_PLACED)
    return qs
```

But this returns a error which says

```
Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.
```

I know why Django is throwing this error, one way I know how to make this work is just rewrite the whole code of paginatedListView in orderList and apply filter before pagination. But is there any other elegant way of doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing this. ListView is already paginated.

Comment: I am using this because I can use {% pagination cl %} from admin_list tags